# state snapshot was created by Terraform v0.12.29, which is newer than

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-aws

I'm using Terraform with s3 as backend, every worked great before but just recently i got the following error message when running terraform `plan` or `apply`

**Error: state snapshot was created by Terraform v0.14.8, which is newer than current v0.12.29; upgrade to Terraform v0.14.8 or greater to work with this state**

The strange thing is I already forced the Terraform version:

```
terraform {
  required_version = ">= 0.12"
}
```

And when I pulled the latest state from s3,the version is still 0.12.29.

```
terraform state pull | grep version

"terraform_version": "0.12.29",
  ....
```

I really have no idea where the version `0.14.8` comes from.

Answer (score 1):

Are you the only developer working on terraform?
Are you running terraform locally or also via some pipeline?
There is a strong possibility that one of your team member upgraded their terraform binary to the v0.14.8 version and applied locally (without updating the remote state) and now you would need to upgrade to that version as well

Its not just the version of the terraform state that you are accessing/running plan against. Terraform cross-references a lot of terraform states internally. So just go inside the remote state bucket and try to find that one specific remote state with different tf version.

Comment: No, my team members also work on terraform and I run it locally. If my team member upgraded their binary to v0.14.8, didn't it change the version in the state file? I still see v0.12.29 in the newest state file.

Comment: You can update local state pn their respective machines, without modifying the remote state

Comment: It's a bit confusing, if their change did not modify the remote state then why Terraform still asks for version `v0.14.8` , where does it get that version ?

Answer (score 1):

Happened to me, my deployment (CICD) failed and left a lock in the TF state.

So I just went and manually removed the lock from my local

`terraform init -backend-config="key=prod/app1.tfstate"`

`terraform force-unlock -force xxxxx-8df6-a7e8-46a8-xxxxxxxxxxxx`

Then I try to redeploy from CI/CD and get that error, because my local was higher version than terraform running in the CI/CD.

In the end, I did this to restore to the previous state:

1. S3: find the state file, restore the old version (versioning enabled in this bucket)
2. Run this again: `terraform init -backend-config="key=prod/app1.tfstate" -reconfigure`

To get the response below with the previous digest value:

```
Successfully configured the backend "s3"! Terraform will automatically
use this backend unless the backend configuration changes.
Error refreshing state: state data in S3 does not have the expected content.

This may be caused by unusually long delays in S3 processing a previous state
update.  Please wait for a minute or two and try again. If this problem
persists, and neither S3 nor DynamoDB are experiencing an outage, you may need
to manually verify the remote state and update the Digest value stored in the
DynamoDB table to the following value: ebf597a8a25619b959baaa34a7b9d905
```

3. Update the dynamo item with the digest above
4. Run deployment again

Answer (score 0):

1. make sure versioning is enable for AWS bucket which maintaining your tfstate files in AWS.
2. by enabling (show version / view) versioning inside bucket i found tfstate file by name.
3. Deleted the latest version which causes mismatch (as in my case it is for terraform version), it add delete marker file for that version. means it actually backup after deletion. you can easily restore original file back by just deleting this added delete marker file.)
4. then i looked into old versions of tfstate files to restore back, by checking history of deployment, downloaded required one (after download ca see details, for me its checking terraform correct version match)
5. then uploaded that old tfstate file to the same location from where i deleted conflicted tfstate file.
6. on resume deployment was getting error like below.

   Error refreshing state: state data in S3 does not have the expected content.

   This may be caused by unusually long delays in S3 processing a previous state
   update.  Please wait for a minute or two and try again. If this problem
   persists, and neither S3 nor DynamoDB are experiencing an outage, you may need
   to manually verify the remote state and update the Digest value stored in the
   DynamoDB table to the following value: b55*****************************

which means there is digest value already present for previous tfstate lock file which need update with this new value, found in DynamoDB>table>view table details.

7. on resume deployment in spinnaker able to complete deployment ( exceptional case : but in my case the latest pipeline was included changes in which there was destroying unused resource, which was created using different provider, hence I required to first revert back the provider first then on resume I able to successfully deploy the changes.)